# mongodb weird RECOVERY database appearing out of no where

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

hello I have a question about my database.
I restarted it about an hour ago and didn't check if my data was still in it.
When I went and looked at the data my own databases where gone and there only was a weird RECOVERY database inside of it with a RECOVERY collection with 3 entries of emails al of which where 'whit@gmx.com' I did not put it there so I am kind of freaked out right now, someone knows what is going?

Comment: Is the server open to the internet? Do you use auth, firewall, or whitelisting of incoming connections?

Comment: I did not have my firewall turned on yesterday I don't know for how long so it was probably a bot, turned my firewall back on immediatly